# "How to correctly transport (subscribe to) an array from a service?

Tags: angular, typescript

"Hi, I'm trying to pass an array from players.service.component.ts to ban-pick.ts. The problem is that the array passed from the service is empty (undefined), and its elements are retrieved from box-player.component.ts. Please help :D. Below, I'm sending the code and HTML."

player.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlayersService {



private playerList: string[] = [];

private playerListObs = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>([]);

constructor() {}

addPlayer(player: string){
  this.playerList.push(player)
  this.playerListObs.next(this.playerList)
  console.log(this.playerList);
    }

 removePlayer(player){
  this.playerList = this.playerList.filter(e => e!== player)
  this.playerListObs.next(this.playerList)
   }

 getPlayerListObs(): Observable<string[]>{
  return this.playerListObs.asObservable()
   }



   }
```

ban-pick.component.ts:

```
            import { Component } from '@angular/core';
            import { PlayersService } from '../services/players.service';



 @Component({
selector: 'app-ban-pick',
   templateUrl: './ban-pick.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./ban-pick.component.css'],
   providers: [PlayersService]
       })
   export class BanPickComponent {

    playerList$: string[] = [];
      currentDisplayedPlayer: string;

  constructor(private playersSerivce: PlayersService) {
this.playersSerivce.getPlayerListObs().subscribe(players => {
  this.playerList$ = players
  if (this.playerList$.length > 0) {
    this.currentDisplayedPlayer = this.playerList$[0]
  }
})

 }

   showNextPlayer() {
  const currentIndex = this.playerList$.indexOf(this.currentDisplayedPlayer)
  console.log(this.playerList$);
   if (currentIndex < this.playerList$.length - 1) {
     this.currentDisplayedPlayer = this.playerList$[currentIndex + 1]
     console.log(this.playerList$);
} else {
     this.currentDisplayedPlayer = this.playerList$[0]
}
 }
```

box-player.component.ts:

```
  import { Component, Version } from '@angular/core';
   import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { PlayersService } from '../services/players.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-box-player',
templateUrl: './box-player.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./box-player.component.css?v='],
 providers: [PlayersService]
     })
  export class BoxPlayerComponent {


 newPlayerInput: string;
maxPlayerAlert = false;
playerList = [];

constructor(private router: Router,
private playersSerivce: PlayersService) {
this.playersSerivce.getPlayerListObs().subscribe(players => {
  this.playerList = players;
  this.validateMaxPlayers();
     })
   }

addPlayer() {
  this.playersSerivce.addPlayer(this.newPlayerInput)
  this.newPlayerInput = ''
  this.validateMaxPlayers();
   }
  


removePlayer(player){
   this.playersSerivce.removePlayer(player)
   this.validateMaxPlayers();
  }

 validateMaxPlayers(){
    this.maxPlayerAlert = this.playerList.length >= 8
   }
  
    }
```

and html to ban-pick.component:

```
  <div>
 <h1 ><span >Gracz {{currentDisplayedPlayer}} dokonuje wyborów! 
</span><button class="btn btn-          primary" 
 (click)="showNextPlayer()">Kolejny gracz</button></h1>
  <br>

   <br>
  <br>
   <div class="separator">






   </div>


   </div>
```

im expecting a solve a problem :D

Comment: Try provide the PlayersService in a higher-level component or in the root module, so that all components share the same instance of the service.

Comment: i have provide PlayersService in app component, but thank you :D